# I want to backup my entire Ubuntu system

Tags: backup, dd

The following table illustrate my partition

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    83891429    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        83891491   625141759   270625134+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        83891493   264253184    90180846    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       264253248   444614939    90180846    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       444616704   446568447      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       495398912   612583423    58592256   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       612585472   625141759     6278144   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      446570496   495396863    24413184   83  Linux
```

Now, I want to backup my system just Linux, can you show me how to fix it using `dd` command or another best ways?

Comment: Why you want to backup with dd? Why don't using Ubuntu's tools?

Comment: When u use the Ubuntu's tools Backups,it show me "Backup failed" & "Ubuntu One has shut down.  Please choose another storage location."

Answer (score 0):

DD will work, however there are probably better tools, like rsync.

Still if you want to use DD, you'll need to do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path/to/backup/drive & dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/path/to/backup/drive &
```

(and so on)